# Factor variable with several levels into binary in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to convert a factor variable in R into binary. In the case of famous iris I want that if it is not versicolor recode it into other. I have thought about something like this, but it doesn't work as expected. What can I do?

```
 for(i in 1:150) {

           if(iris$Species[i]=="virginica"||iris$Species[i]=="setosa") {

            iris$Species[i]="other"
          }
        }
```

Comment: `iris$is_versicolor <- iris$Species == 'versicolor'` or `c('other', 'versicolor')[(iris$Species == 'versicolor') + 1]` if you want to get fancy.

Comment: The loop would work if you first created the new level `levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "other")`. If this is just for learning it's fine, but you shouldn't be rewriting the internal datasets in your session. And the counter should be `for(i in 1:150)`. By the way, a loop is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: @alistaire the (iris$is_versicolor <- iris$Species == 'versicolor') only creates a clumns with versicolor only right? I want two levels versicolor and what is not versicolor into other

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune I was exactly looking for something without for loop or while

Comment: Factors can be problematic to change on the fly because they must be predetermined. You cannot add a level that hasn't been created yet, which is what you were attempting.

Comment: `iris$Species == 'versicolor'` just gives you a logical vector, which is the most useful way to deal with the situation, anyway. The second gives you a character vector. If you want to a factor, you'll need to relevel and drop the excess levels, or use something like `forcats::fct_collapse(iris$Species, versicolor = 'versicolor', other = c('setosa', 'virginica'))`

Comment: @alistaire your suggested code solved the porblem I was thinking to do so ot enable random forest work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reassigning levels using a list can be helpful in cases like these.

```
levels(iris$Species) <- 
  list(versicolor = "versicolor",
       other = c("setosa", "virginica"))

levels(iris$Species)
```

A more general approach (if you have a lot of levels to deal with) could be:

```
levels(iris$Species) <- 
  list(versicolor = "versicolor",
       other = levels(iris$Species)[!levels(iris$Species) %in% "versicolor"])

levels(iris$Species)
```

The downside is that this *will* overwrite your original data.  If it were me, I would do something more like:

```
iris$versicolor  <- iris$Species
levels(iris$versicolor) <- 
  list(versicolor = "versicolor",
       other = levels(iris$versicolor)[!levels(iris$versicolor) %in% "versicolor"])

levels(iris$versicolor)
```

Comment: Nice approach. For readability, probably clearer with `list(verisicolor="verisicolor", other=c("setosa", "virginica"))`. I get that you wanted it general, but perhaps it's so general that newbies get lost.

Comment: I was going for generalizability, but I added your code as the first example for illustration.  Thanks for the pointer, @PierreLafortune

Comment: @benjamin Is this approach preferable to `ifelse` to create dummy variables?

Comment: I can't say for sure. I'm out on vacation for a couple days and didn't bring a proper computer. If I were to investigate this, I'd compare speeds of using this approach, `ifelse`, and something like `model.matrix`. Hopefully I'll remember this when I get back home.

Comment: For creating dummy variables, this wouldn't be my first choice. I've put several options in a gist for consideration. https://gist.github.com/nutterb/92cbd675b80ba184ac8788d5b6c2d847

For simplicity, I would probably just use `model.matrix`.  It's only a few hundred microseconds slower on the `iris` data. So I doubt there would be any real performance hit on larger data sets.  

If you really want to optimize performance, the `dummy_arith` is probably your best bet; it uses implicit conversion from a logical to a numeric.